# Can not debug iOS crash report

Tags: ios, react-native

my app is being rejected by Apple store. They say the app crashes on start and have send me this crash report. On my device (iPhone 13 Pro) the app runs perfectly after I install it from testflight.

Please help me identify what is wrong.

This is my `npx react-native info`

```
System:
  OS: macOS 14.4
  CPU: (10) arm64 Apple M1 Max
  Memory: 421.56 MB / 32.00 GB
  Shell:
    version: "5.9"
    path: /bin/zsh
Binaries:
  Node:
    version: 18.17.1
    path: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/bin/node
  Yarn: Not Found
  npm:
    version: 10.0.0
    path: ~/WORK/foodobox/foodbox-web/node_modules/.bin/npm
  Watchman:
    version: 2024.01.22.00
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
Managers:
  CocoaPods:
    version: 1.12.1
    path: /Users/velinkerkov/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/bin/pod
SDKs:
  iOS SDK:
    Platforms:
      - DriverKit 23.4
      - iOS 17.4
      - macOS 14.4
      - tvOS 17.4
      - visionOS 1.1
      - watchOS 10.4
  Android SDK: Not Found
IDEs:
  Android Studio: 2023.2 AI-232.10227.8.2321.11479570
  Xcode:
    version: 15.3/15E204a
    path: /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
  Java:
    version: 17.0.10
    path: /usr/bin/javac
  Ruby:
    version: 3.1.0
    path: /Users/velinkerkov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/bin/ruby
npmPackages:
  "@react-native-community/cli": Not Found
  react: Not Found
  react-native: Not Found
  react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
  "*react-native*": Not Found
Android:
  hermesEnabled: Not found
  newArchEnabled: Not found
iOS:
  hermesEnabled: Not found
  newArchEnabled: Not found
```

Link to [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/cqGhV3S2)

Comment: Delete the app, iCloud and anything related off of your iPhone. Turn off WiFi and cellular. Usually An Apple crash can be duplicated by using a clean iPhone or iPad. Also Google “symbolicating” crash reports.

Comment: How to see the Google "symbolicating" crash reports ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/adding-identifiable-symbol-names-to-a-crash-report

Comment: In case you are using Firebase you might need to update your dependencies.
I know this is a flutter thread but it‘s the same native error (https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/12442).

Comment: @MichaelBahl I will try this today. It is very strange since everything works on my devices.

Comment: In case my hint helped, can you give an upvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hit this and the issue turned out to be react-native-firebase when built for iOS 17.4.

I found a couple of related issues (see links below). In my case I just needed to update all react-native-firebase dependencies to the latest versions (currently 19.0.1), and the crash disappeared.

https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/7695
https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/12442